# How to update point spread function of blind deconbolution by conjugate gradient?

Tags: filters, convolution, linear-systems, deconvolution, optimization

There is an **unblurred image $g$** and a **blurred image $x$**.

Their relationship is expressed by the following formula using **$psf$**(point spread fucntion, size is $5×5$ kernel).

$g = x \otimes psf\tag 1$

where $\otimes$ is 2D convoluition.
If I write the above formula by matrix operation, also, I am thinking about blind deconvolution

$\nabla^2\mathbf{g} = \nabla^2\mathbf{x\;PSF^{(k)}}\tag 2$

where, $\mathbf{g}$ and $\mathbf{x}$ is $N×N$ matrices, and $\mathbf{PSF}$ is $N^2×N^2$  Toeplitz matrices,$\nabla^2$ is the second order differential operator.

I want to solve an optimization problem that incorporates Equation $(2)$.

In the process of optimizing $\mathbf{x}$, I also want to optimize $\mathbf{PSF}$ by the conjugate gradient method.

$$\mathbf{PSF}^{(k+1)} \leftarrow \text{Conjugate Gradient Method}(\mathbf{\nabla^2g}, \;\mathbf{\nabla^2x}^{(k+1)},\; \mathbf{PSF}^{(k)})$$

**[What I want to do]**

**In the process of optimizing $\mathbf{x}$, I also want to optimize $\mathbf{PSF^{(k)}}$ by the conjugate gradient method.**

**[What I want you to tell me]**

From the following questions, [[How to estimate filters using conjugate gradient?]](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/26420/how-to-estimate-filters-using-conjugate-gradient)

should I think of deconvolution in frequency space?

Or should I update psf by matrix operation in a different way?

Comment: Why would you want to solve this that way?

Comment: I want to solve $\min\frac{1}{2}\Vert{x^{(k)} \otimes psf^{(k)}-g}\Vert_2^2+\Vert w\circ (D x^{(k)})\Vert_1 \tag 1$.

Comment: I thought so but you write it not well. Edit your question with what you wrote on the comment.

Comment: Sorry,　Comment editing has expired.

Comment: I want to solve $\min\frac{1}{2}\Vert{x^{(k)} \otimes psf^{(k)}-g}\Vert_2^2+\Vert w\circ (D x^{(k)})\Vert_1 \tag 1$.
This optimization probelm has two update process. First, update $x^{(k)}$ by solving ADMM, second, update $psf^{(k)}$  is calculated by solving Equation(1) using the conjugated gradient.

Comment: I refer to this treatise and pseudocode.　[Kim et al. supplementary material](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/microscopy-and-microanalysis/article/abs/application-of-blind-deconvolution-based-on-the-new-weighted-l1norm-regularization-with-alternating-direction-method-of-multipliers-in-light-microscopy-images/401C8DE006A6D7EBC597CB39E2554559#supplementary-materials)

Comment: Solving for both $ x $ and $ psf $ means you have Blind Deconvolution problem.

Comment: Yes, I have a Blind Deconvolution problem. So I don't know if psf should be handled by toeplitz matrix or convolution kernel ($5x5$ etc.)

Comment: I have answered on Blind Deconvolution (https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/75664). You may read and evaluate. Once you do, please focus your question and I will answer.

Comment: I read past questions. I have a rough understanding of Blind deconvolution. However,  I didn't know how to update $H$ with the conjugate gradient method.　$H$ is an unknown linear shift invariant blur operator.

Comment: Should I understand this site that was linked to a previous question?
[Orthogonal Projection onto the Unit Simplex](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2402504/orthogonal-projection-onto-the-unit-simplex)

Comment: Or should I minimize following equation using the conjugate gradient method? $$\mathrm argmin_{PSF}\Vert{\nabla^2 x^{(k+1)}  \mathbf{PSF}^{(k)}-\nabla^2 g}\Vert_2^2+\Vert  \mathbf{PSF}^{(k)}\Vert_2 \tag 1$$

Comment: You're mixing things. Conjugate Gradient Descent is a method to solve Linear System of Equations. It's a tool to solve a step of the problem. You don't need to change the formulation of the problem for it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Comment: You may +1 the links. If you focus the question here I will try answer.

Comment: I read it, but I didn't think that this would lead to the conjugate gradient method.

Comment: Conjugate Gradient is a tool to solve linear system of equations. You may chose any method to solve those. Conjugate Gradient isn’t uniquely required in this case.